# Merge: Which one is the stronger branch?

Tags: mercurial

I'd like to merge a branch into the develop branch. I have always thought that the branch I want to merge is stronger that the currently active branch. But the develop branch seems to be stronger.

How can I force `hg` to priorize branches?

Comment: What do you mean by "stronger"?

Comment: In `file.txt` (branch), a couple of characters have been removed. Merging this branch back into develop, the characters are there again (because they have not been removed in develop). I'd like to say "delete them, because they have been deleted in the branch".

Comment: That's not what should have happened.  When you merge, the result should contain all the changes from both branches. Is it possible that the user did either of the following? 1. When you merge, the result is not automatically committed so the user could put those characters back in before committing.  2. If you merge and there are conflicts then the user is asked to resolve those conflicts and they could have chosen to resolve them incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that my version of Mercurial and SourceTree is very old. After updating, it worked just fine.